# Proving a result of a function on $L^1[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> For every $\phi\in C[-1,1]$ define $f(\phi)=\phi(0)$.
>
> 1. Verify that $f\in C[-1,1]^*$ and compute $||f||$
> 2. Prove that there is no Function $g\in L^1[-1,1]$ such that $f(\phi)=\int\limits_{-1}^1\phi gdx$ for all $\phi\in C[-1,1]$.
> 3. Identifying $C[-1,1]$ with a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}[-1,1]$ prove that standard embedding of $L^1[-1,1]$  into $L^{\infty}[-1,1]^*$
>      is not onto

I was able to do the part 1:
Linearity is trivial.
Then by considering the continuity at $0$, we have $|f(\phi)|=|\phi(0)|\leq \epsilon+|\phi(x)|\leq\epsilon+||\phi||$.
Thus it gives the boundedness and $||f||\leq 1$.
And by taking the constant function $\phi=1$ we have $||f||\geq 1$.
Therefore $||f||=1$

For part 2:
I guess I can use the functions $\phi_n=1/n$  and contradict the fact that $g\in L^1$. that is $\int|g|<\infty$. Is it correct.

And for 3, I'm clueless. what I know is that $L^1[-1,1]$ space is the all $g\in[-1,1]$ such that $\int\limits_{-1}^1|g|<\infty$.
And $L^{\infty}[-1,1]$ gives the bounded functions on $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 1):

For part three, assume the contrary that it is onto. Then for such an $f\in C[-1,1]^{\ast}$, as $C[-1,1]$ is a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}[-1,1]$, Hahn-Banach gives us some extension $\overline{f}\in L^{\infty}[-1,1]^{\ast}$ of $f$ such that $\overline{f}(\phi)=f(\phi)$ for $\phi\in C[-1,1]$. Then the surjective map gives some $g\in L^{1}[-1,1]$ such that $\overline{f}(\phi)=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\phi(x)g(x)dx$ for any $\phi\in L^{\infty}[-1,1]$. Realizing $\phi\in C[-1,1]$ and keep in mind that $\overline{f}(\phi)=f(\phi)$, this contradicts the result in part two.

For part two, let $\phi_{n}(x)=n^{2}x+n$ for $-1/n\leq x\leq 0$ and $\phi_{n}(x)=-n^{2}x+n$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/n$ and zero otherwise. Then $f(\phi_{n})=n$. On the other hand, given $\epsilon>0$, since $g$ is continuous at $0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(0)|<\epsilon$ for $|x|<\delta$. Then for large $n$, 
\begin{align*}
|f(\phi_{n})-g(0)|&=\left|\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\phi_{n}(x)g(x)dx-\int_{-1}^{1}\phi_{n}(x)g(0)dx\right|\\
&\leq\displaystyle\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|\phi_{n}(x)||g(x)-g(0)|dx\\
&\leq\epsilon\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}\phi_{n}(x)dx\\
&=\epsilon, 
\end{align*}
this means that $f(\phi_{n})\rightarrow g(0)$, this is a contradiction since $f(\phi_{n})\rightarrow\infty$.

**Edit:**
I overlooked that as if $g$ were continuous, the above argument for part two is only valid for continuous $g$.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. But can you please tell what is exactly meant by "embedding" is it an injective Linear transformation from $L^1$ to $L^{\infty}$? 
 

If so did you take $\phi$ as the embedding? Sorry  that I couldn't get it at once..

Comment: That means for every $x^{\ast}\in L^{\infty}[-1,1]^{\ast}$, there is a $g\in L^{-1}[-1,1]$ such that $x^{\ast}(\phi)=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\phi(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: Well.. I think I haven't understood the meaning of Embedding properly.. Can you please suggest a reference so that I can go through

Comment: Any Banach space book will do the job. For example look for Robert Megginson one.

Comment: Have a look at [Cohn's treatment](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461469551) of the Riesz Representation theorems.

Comment: By embedding we understand that the Identity operator $I: L^{1}([-1,1]) \to (L^{\infty}([-1,1]))^{*}$ is well defined (thus we can see $L^{1}$ as a subset of $(L^{\infty})^{*}$) and it is continuous. Note that, @gune, there is a typo in your question, $L^{1}$ isn't embedded in $L^{\infty}$. If you haven't seen yet, this example you posted is in Brezis Book, chapter 4.

Comment: Thank you everyone. ANd yes I adjusted the typo. It was $L^{\infty}[-1,1]^*$

Comment: Well.. I think my proposed solution for part 2 is wrong...

Comment: Look at the edited post, I included the proof for part two.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One last clarification.. you have mentioned that $g$ is continuous at $0$. But may I know why is that? Does, $g\in L^1$ implies $g$ is continuous ?

Comment: And also in the first line why does it happens? Because $g(0)=f(g)=\int(g(x))^2$ isn't it?

Comment: I'm quite sure that some small alteration could be done and come to the solution. Or else your answer is correct and I might have understood it in a wrong way. 
But anyway here in this link also there is a method: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410911/prove-that-there-is-no-function-g-in-l1-1-1-such-that-f-phi-int-limits/3410920#3410911

Comment: I overlooked as if $g$ is continuous. Anyway, The area of $\phi_{n}$ is $1$, so $g(0)=g(0)\int\cdots$.